# Jsp, connection pool and mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, connection, pool

I've going around this for a while, yet seem to be lacking the knowledge.

Can someone paste a quick guide on how to implement such thing. I'm a bit puzzled about what context is and what's his role is the whole situation.

At the end point, I already have a connection class, even a connection pool class with boneCp, yet I've no idea on how to run it on server start and not when a Jsp call comes in.

Thx for the help.

Comment: can you details what you want to know actually?

Comment: Sure. I have an Apache server with mysql. Once an API call is being received at the Apache, right now, I'm creating a connection class which connect to the Db, needless to say it's a bad practice. What I would like to do is on server start to create a pool of connections and mange it with is my Java.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, I have always used Spring Framework to manage my connection pool and supply it to the controller for usage. I get the pool from the container.

Comment: Can you supply with a tutorial on how to achieve this?